# Unittesting in Borland C++Builder 2006

Tags: unit-tests

Which unit testing framework would you use in Borland C++Builder 2006?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like something that a search engine could help with.

I found this thread that may help - http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1411445&page=9

Personally, I've used cppUnit for other c++ code and have been quite happy with it. I haven't used it with C++ builder, so ymmv.